# How to select image and store inside the project folder using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.I need to select image and store it into my project folder using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

> index.html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 bannerimagefile" ng-controller="imgController">
<form  name="form">
<label for="bannerimage" accesskey="B"><span class="required">*</span> Banner Image</label>
<input type="file" class="filestyle" data-size="lg" name="bannerimage" id="bannerimage" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="20MB" ngf-min-height="100" ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}">
<label for="bannerimage" accesskey="B" ><span class="required">*</span> View Image</label>
<div style="padding-bottom:10px;">
<img ng-src="{{attachImage}}" border="0" name="bannerimage" style="width:70px; height:70px;">
</div>
<div><input type="button" id="btn" ng-click="submitImage();" value="Upload" /></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
var app=angular.module('testImage',['ngFileUpload']);
app.controller('imgController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.submitImage=function(){
        console.log('image',$scope.file);
    }

});
```

Here My requirement is when user will select the image it will display inside image tag and when user will click on upload button it will save inside the project folder.Please help me.

Comment: You can't do that without some code running in your server. AngularJS scripts run on the user's browser, you project folder is in your server and its not open to write through internet.

Comment: I am also using `PHP ` for backend.Save image path into database.

Comment: This is quite easy, however your question is pretty broad. Check FileReader for client + php file upload.

Comment: @dfsq : Can you please edit your answer ? Or share any example link .

Comment: There are many-many example on the web. Just google something like "angular file upload".